# link multiple audio tracks to one video track in Premiere CC

Tags: video, premiere, audio, sync

I shoot TMZ-type webisodes, where multiple people are throwing jokes around a news room.  I'm considering buying 4 lavaliere mics for my 4 performers so I can isolate their audio during editing.

I want to keep the 4 audio tracks synched with the video track as I cut and rearrange the footage. Using Premiere CC, how would I link the multiple audio tracks to the single video track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can link multiple clips as you would link two clips. First, put all the audio and video tracks you want in your timeline and arrange them using the timecodes, manual adjustments or however you prefer to align the individual recordings (I'm assuming you have a method for that, since you removed that part of the question in the last edit). Then select all clips that you want to link, right-click on one of them and select "link" (if some of them are already linked, you will only see an "unlink" option, in that case unlink them, select them again and then link them alltogether). You could also choose to group them, which yields a slightly different effect.

Check the [Premiere Pro Support Page](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/editing-audio-timeline-panel.html#link_and_unlink_video_and_audio_clips) for more information on linking clips, as well as [this page](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-elements/using/grouping-linking-disabling-clips.html) on linking and grouping clips in Premiere Elements (it's works quite similar in Premiere Pro).

One more tip: In the program preferences under "Generel", you have the option "Display out of sync indicators for unlinked clips", which will show you when clips you linked at some point are out of sync even if you unlinked them later on. This might be helpful for an editing process with several independent audio clips.

Comment: I thought I tried linking multiple audio tracks this morning and it failed. I'll have to try that again! Thanks for the answer. I'll mark your answer as The Accepted Answer once I test this.

Comment: Let me know if it worked! At least it did when  I tried it ...

Comment: It worked just fine! I'm not sure what went wrong with my first test, which it appeared to fail. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Well I'm glad it worked! :)